# Migrate document library content from SP 2003 to existing SP 2010/13

Tags: 2013, 2010, 2003

What is the best way to migrate document libraries from an SP 2003 to an existing SP 2010 or 2013 (we have both) environment which preserves the nested structure of the document library?

Comment: Welcome to SharePoint StackExchange :) , Could you please take a quick tour at https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/tour to get informed badge! Thank you for your contribution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends :-)
If the document metadata must be preserved then ShareGate or similar migration tools might be the best solution.  The same answer applies if you have to contract with a supplier in order to develop the code that can transfer the content. 
Otherwise a recursive powershell script will do the trick

Comment: I am trying a powershell script but running into errors.

Comment: [void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint")

Export-SPWeb "http://intranet/sites/programmeoffice" -itemurl "/document" -path "c:\temp\documents.cmp" -IncludeVersions All

Comment: Export-SPWeb Cannot find an SPWeb Object with Id or Url

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of ways depending upon requirement.

1. Simple and easy way but may be costly...use 3rd party tools to migrate the documents. Some tools offer free trial as well.
2. If you don't need meta data then open the libraries with explorer and manually copy the documents.
3. Another way which is expensive, building 2007 and 2010 farms then using database backup method migrate 2003 db to 2013.
4. You can also try to export the document library from 2003 farm then change version inside cab file then import into 2013 far.

Read more here: https://absolute-sharepoint.com/2013/08/how-to-move-a-list-from-sharepoint-2010-to-sharepoint-2013.html